# Hovering over the legend will hide all lines except the corresponding line

Tags: python, bokeh

When you hover over the legend, all lines except the corresponding line will be hidden. How to achieve this via bokeh, python or javascript. I have no idea what to do to achieve this function. It would be great if we could provide a simple example with three lines.Thanks for your help.My code example is as follows:

```
import bokeh.palettes as bp
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import LinearAxis, Range1d, NumeralTickFormatter, Legend
from bokeh.layouts import column
import numpy as np


if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = 5
    color_list2 = bp.magma(num)
    color_list1 = bp.viridis(num)
    plotTools = 'box_zoom, wheel_zoom, pan, tap, crosshair, hover, reset, save'
    p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=400, x_range=(0, 1000), y_range=(-2.5, -1.5),
               tools=plotTools, toolbar_location='right', active_scroll='wheel_zoom', )
    p.title.text = 'Hover and Hide'
    items_c1 = []
    i = 0
    pictures = []
    labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    for label in labels:
        n = np.random.randint(low=3, high=6)
        xs = np.random.random(n) * 1000
        y1s = np.random.random(n) - 2.5
        temp_line = p.line(xs, y1s, line_width=2, color=color_list1[i % num],
                           alpha=0.3, hover_color='red', hover_alpha=0.9)  # , legend_label=label
        items_c1.append((label + '_BER', [temp_line]))
        i = i + 1
        if i % num == 0:
            legend_1 = Legend(items=items_c1)
            p.add_layout(legend_1, 'left')
            p.xaxis.axis_label = 'run_time'
            p.yaxis[0].axis_label = 'BER'
            p.legend[0].orientation = 'vertical'
            p.legend[0].location = 'bottom_center'
            p.legend[0].click_policy = 'hide'
            pictures.append(p)

            p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=400, x_range=(0, 1000), y_range=(-2.5, -1.5),
                       tools=plotTools, toolbar_location='right', active_scroll='wheel_zoom', )
            items_c1 = []
    file = "test_ask_5"
    file_path = file + '.html'
    output_file(file_path)
    show(column(pictures))
```

Comment: Please, share your code.

Comment: OK, I've pasted my code samples.

Comment: Please, please don't write java where you need to write javascript. You're enerving the java crowd.

Comment: Sorry, I'm too careless. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution below hides all lines but the one that is being clicked (not hovered). This code works for Bokeh v1.3.4

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import CustomJS

colors = ['orange', 'cyan', 'lightgreen']

p = figure()
lines = [p.line(np.arange(10), np.random.random(10), line_color = colors[i], line_width = 3, legend=colors[i], name=colors[i]) for i in range(3)]

code = '''if(Bokeh != 'undefined' && (Bokeh.active_line === 'undefined' || Bokeh.active_line == null)) 
          { 
              Bokeh.active_line = cb_obj.name; 
          }'''
[line.js_on_change('visible', CustomJS(code = code)) for line in lines]

code = ''' for(i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                if (lines[i].name == Bokeh.active_line) {
                    lines[i].visible = true
                }
                else {
                    lines[i].visible = false
                }
            } 
            Bokeh.active_line = null'''
p.js_on_event('tap', CustomJS(args = {'lines' : lines}, code = code))

code = '''  for(i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                lines[i].visible = true
            } 
            Bokeh.active_line = null'''
p.js_on_event('reset', CustomJS(args = dict(lines = lines), code = code))

p.legend.click_policy = 'hide'

show(p)
```

The first callback is applied to all glyph renderers (lines) and is being triggered when the line must be hidden, that is when a user clicks a legend item. The callback just sets the global variable `Bokeh.active_line` which remembers the renderer (line) name, e.g. "orange" or "cyan"

The second callback is attached to the plot canvas and is triggered every time the user clicks anywhere on the plot. What is basically does is inverting the glyphs (lines) visibility. It only shows the line specified by 
`Bokeh.active_line`

The third callback is attached to the plot and is triggered when user clicks on the reset tool in the toolbar. It restores visibility of all lines.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have helped me a lot, and yours solution is very close to the demand. I will learn your code seriously.

Comment: On stackoverflow if an answer is helpfull to you, you should accept it by clicking the check mark on the left side so others know this is a good answer. Thanks